# Get attachment from single page by id, and paged it. (Wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress

How to get attachment from single page by ID, and set 12 img per page?

'post_parent' => 145, // not working, but without this param I get all attachments

```
<?php
                $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
                $attachment = new WP_Query( array(
                    'post_parent' => 145, // not working, but without this param I get all attachments
                    'post_status' => 'inherit',
                    'post_type' => 'attachment',
                    'post_mime_type' => 'image/jpeg,image/gif,image/jpg,image/png',
                    'posts_per_page'  => 12,
                    'paged'           => $paged
                ) );
                if ( $attachment->have_posts() ) :
                    while ( $attachment->have_posts() ) : $attachment->the_post(); 

            ?>
                        <div class="gallery__item"><a href="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment->ID , false ); ?>" data-fancybox><img src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment->ID , false ); ?>" alt=""></a></div>
            <?php

                    endwhile; 
                    wp_reset_postdata();
                endif;
            ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what the problem was. I use **post_parent** and tells post ID, thinking that take all attachments from this post, but WP_Query returns me ID's of images.

I get all id's of images in array with **get_post_gallery()**

```
$gal = get_post_gallery(11,false);
```

and explode it

```
$ids = explode(',', $gal['ids']);
```

after then everything worked!

also I use **post__in** insted **post_parent**

The final code:

```
<?php
                $gal = get_post_gallery(11,false);
                $ids = explode(',', $gal['ids']);
                $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
                $attachment = new WP_Query( array(
                    'post__in' => $ids,
                    'post_status' => 'inherit',
                    'post_type' => 'attachment',
                    'post_mime_type' => 'image/jpeg,image/gif,image/jpg,image/png',
                    'posts_per_page'  => 12,
                    'paged'           => $paged
                ) );
                if ($attachment -> have_posts() ) :
                    while ($attachment -> have_posts() ) : $attachment -> the_post(); 
            ?>
                        <div class="gallery__item"><a href="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url(); ?>" data-fancybox><img src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url(); ?>" alt=""></a></div>
            <?php

                    endwhile; 
                    wp_reset_postdata();
                endif;
            ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

By looking to the code, you are using **post_parent** which is quiet clearly explain in

[Codex WP Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Mime_Type_Parameters)

which basically says that only the post that has child will be return of the currently provided post id i.e. 145.

I think you have to use **post_parent__in** than the current one.

Hope this works for you.

Thank You

Comment: post_parent__in and post_in return query like

object(WP_Query)#665 (48) { ["query"]=> array(6) { ["post__in"]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(11) [1]=> int(145) } ["post_status"]=> string(7)

but after then my function show emty results.

Comment: "have not posts" is says